# Unexpected Return - Template Matching (Basic)

Tags: python, opencv

The following error is appearing when trying to template match an image. I do not understand the error or the value of `dst_ptr`. Could someone explain to me what the error represents? I am following a tutorial for OpenCV and the code works on the tutors machine, I believe I have the correct packages installed etc as I have used OpenCV in the past, just not for feature detection

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1230: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dst.data == (uchar*)dst_ptr in function 'cvShowImage'`

I have altered the key value within the result variable (the last parameter in the matchTemplate, however, this is not the problem)

The code functions correctly until the result variable is attempted to be displayed.

```
import cv2

template = cv2.imread("template.jpg", 0)
frame = cv2.imread("players.jpg", 0)

cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
cv2.imshow("Template", template)

result = cv2.matchTemplate(frame, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
print(max_val, max_loc)

cv2.circle(result, max_loc, 15, 255, 2)
cv2.imshow("Matching", result)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The expected result is for the image to display a template matching result.
The output returns an error, specified earlier.

Comment: This code works for me and I tested on a machine with OpenCV `3.4.4` (upgraded to `4.0.0` and it works as well)